# Unitarity gauge

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, gauge-theory, unitarity, gauge

Weinberg in Chapter 21, section 21.1, QFT 2, says that, in unitarity gauge $\tilde{\phi}_n(x) = \gamma^{-1}_{nm}(x)\phi_m(x)$,

> we do not have degrees of freedom with negative probability, like time-like gauge bosons.

I don't quite understand this. Please let me know if you have any insights.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93590/gupta-bleuler-formalism). Have you illustrated the simple point in the Abelian Higgs model first? It is bad karma to plunge into the general case before reassuring yourself of the obviousness of a simple particular case.

Comment: Could you give this question some more context? Without reading that section of Weinberg I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, Cosmas, thank you, that part I do understand, I didn't want to surmise in the question, but you are absolutely right, perhaps I need to go through details carefully to gain better clarity.